# How to remove visible margin on the sides of the echo area?

Tags: themes, echo-area

I have a question that might be unique. I am new to emacs, so please forgive me (or point me in the right direction) if I missed something obvious or say something wrong.

My problem is that I have made my echo-area a darker color than its surrounding, and now I can see a gap on the sides of the echo area. If I could color that area, or delete the padding/border that is causing that gap, or anything else to remedy the situation, I would be happy to hear it.

I will attach a picture and provide some potentially not useful context below.

I have disabled my mode-line, and I am using the symon package to put the mode line info in the echo area.

I have colored the echo-area using

`(with-current-buffer " *Echo Area 1*" (face-remap-add-relative 'default :background "#222"))`

and it only (currently) colors the idle mode.

I am using the "doom-one" theme from the "doom-themes" package. The picture shows the left side but both sides have this gap.

Let me know if there is any other info I should provide. Thank you for your time!

[image: my emacs corner]

[image: i made a red one to make the problem more visible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! It was the fringe. This question had the answer:

[How to disable margin inside a frame](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32503/how-to-disable-margin-inside-a-frame)

and setting `(fringe-mode 0)` seems to solve it, though I wish there was a way to only turn off the fringe in the echo-area, or have the echo-area overlap it or something.

Comment: You can accept your own answer.